# Can't get MySQL working

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have Ubuntu 16.04 server and wordpress installed. I have a wired problem which I couldn't find any solution for it.

I get `Error establishing a database connection` error in my wordpress site. I get `#2002 - No such file or directory The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).` error in phpmyadmin when I try to login.

I found these two links talking about my problem: [How To Debug the Wordpress "Error Establishing Database Connection"](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-debug-the-wordpress-error-establishing-database-connection) and [Why do I often get this error when accessing phpmyadmin?](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/why-do-i-often-get-this-error-when-accessing-phpmyadmin)

The first one says I should see `mysql` when I run `sudo netstat -plt` but I don't! I ran `sudo systemctl start mysql` and first it said mysql is masked so I unmasked it and ran it again. but still I can't see mysql in netstat.

The second link says about swap which is enabled in my server.

This is my website's link: [etuts.ir](http://etuts.ir)

Comment: Are you running mysql on the same server?

Comment: Yes I think!! Actually your question is a little new to me I mean I thought that's the only way! Anyways yes I just have one server.

Comment: It isnt the only way to run an app. Mostly medium to large scale apps never run mysql on the app server. can u connect to mysql via the cli?

Comment: This is likely an Ubuntu administration question. Try asking on https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem occurs when `mysql-server` is not running.
Try to install it with the following command:
`sudo apt-get install mysql-server` 
Don't worry about loosing data, it will just install the service and your data will be safe.
Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks!! that's wired! It was working well before. That solved the problem

Answer (score -1):

I had a very similar problem but re-installing `mysql-server` didn't solve my problem! What I needed to do was configuring `swap` for my server. You can follow this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04) to install swap in your ubuntu server